# Tkinter LabelFrame not coming on screen despite correct syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, tkinter-layout

I am using VSC. I am creating a Chess timer project, for that I need my buttons of two players to be inside a LabelFrame so that I don't have to mess around with grid option as it makes life very difficult. I will place the Buttons inside the LabelFrame which will be packed on the main root page and then do the correct padding inside the LabelFrame to Centralize the buttons.

Example: (a screenshot from my previous Tkinter project):

[image: What I want it to look like]

Here the buttons are centered inside the LabelFrame using Grid option and the LabelFrame itself is .packed() on screen.

Here is my current code:

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import * 
from TkUtil import Centre #My own custom module that centers the window on the screen of the user
root=Tk()
root.title("Chess Timer")
root.config(bg="white")
Centre(root,600,400) #USed my own self made module, no Error in this line :)
root.iconbitmap("D:\Coding\DevenIcon.ico")
lab=Label(root, text="Deven's Chess Timer", font="Helvetica 24", bg="white").pack(pady=10)
R_title=LabelFrame(root,text="Welcome To Game Hub!", font=("Helvetica",20,"bold"),padx=5,pady=5, width="30", bg="white")
R_title.pack(padx=10)
#labf=LabelFrame(root, text="BUTTONS", padx=5, pady=5).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image: Why is LabelFrame widget not coming on screen?]

How can I place the LabelFrame widget on screen?

Comment: When you use `lab=Label(...).pack(...)`, `None` is stored in `lab` not a `Label` object. I don't think is the cause of your problem but avoid calling `.pack`/`.grid`/`.place` on the same line that you created the widget

Comment: There's nothing in your labelframe, so its height is going to be 1 pixel.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked after I put something inside the LabelFrame! :)